# WAV header indicates an unsupported format. in google cloud speech to text API

Tags: node.js, audio, speech-to-text

I am trying to upload my WAV file first to the bucket which is uploaded successfully and then using that URI to transcript while using google cloud speech to text API but it gives this error that the config object I am giving is probably wrong :

```
(node:15728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: WAV header indicates an unsupported format.
    at Object.callErrorFromStatus (C:\Users\Talha\Desktop\transcription backend\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:26)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\Talha\Desktop\transcription backend\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:176:52)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\Talha\Desktop\transcription backend\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:342:141)
    at Object.onReceiveStatus (C:\Users\Talha\Desktop\transcription backend\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:305:181)
    at C:\Users\Talha\Desktop\transcription backend\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:124:78
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)
(node:15728) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:15728) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate
the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The code I wrote is:

```
const filePath = "i_think_arthur.wav"; // WAV file

// Google Cloud storage
const bucketName = "<bucket name>"; // Must exist in your Cloud Storage
const keyFilename = "<path to service account key>";

const uploadToGcs = async () => {
  const storage = new Storage({
    projectId: "<my project id>",
    keyFilename,
  });

  const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
  const fileName = path.basename(filePath);

  await bucket.upload(filePath);

  return `gs://${bucketName}/${fileName}`;
};

// Upload to Cloud Storage first, then detects speech in the audio file
uploadToGcs()
  .then(async (gcsUri) => {
    const audio = {
      uri: gcsUri,
    };

    const config = {
      encoding: "OGG_OPUS",
      sampleRateHertz: 48000,
      // encoding: "LINEAR16",
      languageCode: "en-US",
      audioChannelCount: 2,
      enableSeparateRecognitionPerChannel: true,
    };

    const request = {
      audio,
      config,
    };

    speechClient
      .longRunningRecognize(request)
      .then((data) => {
        const operation = data[0];

        // The following Promise represents the final result of the job
        return operation.promise();
      })
      .then((data) => {
        const results = _.get(data[0], "results", []);
        const transcription = results
          .map((result) => result.alternatives[0].transcript)
          .join("\n");
        console.log(`Transcription: ${transcription}`);
      });
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("ERROR:", err);
  });
```

I'll appreciate any type of your help in this problem, thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was going through pretty much the same thing.

I was trying to make a mix of samples and try to recognise a particular voice. What I did was using OpenShot Video Editor to mix the audio samples, and https://online-audio-converter.com/ to convert the .mp4 file to wav.

Specifically, the following settings in the converter website work with the default settings on the Google Cloud Scripts:

In Advanced Settings:

- Sample Rate: 16000 KHz
- Channels: 1

And now you have an audio file you can work with on Google Cloud's `speech-to-text`!

Comment: But it's not necessary that you would have that kind of control on your audio files. This is perhaps not the solution one would be looking for.